# Reactjs build failed attempted import error: 'widget' is not exported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tradingview-api

I created a new React project with Typescript and I copy and paste old file from another project which is just .jsx file. This file is importing a class called widget like this.

index.jsx

```
import { widget } from "../charting_library/charting_library";
```

This import didn't work due to linting issues so I add an entry to .eslintignore file like this

```
src/pages/instuments/technicalAnalysis/charting_library/*.js
```

Then it worked perfectly fine with `npm run start`. But when I tried to build using `npm run build command.
It throws this error

> Attempted import error: 'widget' is not exported from
> '../charting_library/charting_library'.

**the widget should be in the charting_libbray folder. Otherwise, it won't work with npm run start as well.**

On the other hand, charting_library is a folder

```
charting_library
-charting_library.cjs.js
-charting_library.d.ts
-charting_library.esm.js
-charting_library.js
-charting_library.standalone.js
-**package.json**
```

package.json is like this

```
{
  "private": true,
  "description": "CL v20.033 (internal id 9df149da @ 2021-11-17T10:20:51.511Z)",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "charting_library.cjs.js",
  "module": "charting_library.esm.js",
  "types": "charting_library.d.ts"
}

import { widget } from "../charting_library/charting_library";
```

What does this charting_library part refer to? When I try click+ctrl on the import statement it points to charting_library.d.ts file. I think that is the reason for this error. If so how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the 2nd `charting_library` string at import statement: https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples/issues/86#issuecomment-727867852